# ImportError: cannot import name 'DjangoFilterBackend'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

After upgrading to **`Django REST framework 3.7`** I got following error

```
  File "/home/jpg/Projects/django2x/sample/views.py", line 24, in <module>
    from rest_framework.filters import DjangoFilterBackend
ImportError: cannot import name 'DjangoFilterBackend'
```

and here is my view

```
from rest_framework.filters import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import viewsets


class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Foo_Serializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('foo_bar', 'bar_foo')
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend`** was depricated in [**DRF : 3.7**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#370).
 So from **`DRF 3.7`** onwards you should install [**django-filter**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html) package to use the **`DjangoFilterBackend`** in the views.

---

You can update the `< DRF 3.6` style filters as,

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Foo_Serializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('foo_bar', 'bar_foo')
```

**Note:** the **`filter_fields`** attribute is chnaged to **`filterset_fields`** in newer versions of django-filter